# Excel automatically sort column of numbers

Tags: excel, function, sorting, auto

I am looking to automatically sort a column of numbers in descending order without touching the sort button, or VBA.

Unfortunately I am trying to achieve this in a work environment where I have no access to VBA and excel is not one of the latest versions that contains the new SORT function in 365.

It is quite literally a column of numbers, and the numbers are automatically updated as they are totals of rows of smaller numbers elsewhere, and these change based on something else - so this specific column will always change numbers, but I need the column to automatically keep on top of sorting numbers by descending order.

I tried using rank.eq and some other bits with adding a 1 to each row to avoid duplicates, but this buggered it up if more than two duplicates was found.  Is there anything I can do at all? Even if it involves going a very long way round it and building extra tables and things etc.

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be easier to see your data and without being able to use a spill range, it's impossible to know how many rows. I also think you're intending to use `LARGE` function rather than `RANK`.

If you had your numbers in column `A`, you could drag the following formula down the appropriate number of rows to get the numbers sorted... (starting in cell `B1`)

```
=LARGE(A$1:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A),1),ROW())
```

[image]

If you can get your numbers in a table, you could use a similar formula but the table would ensure the appropriate rows exist (assume table name is `Table1` and note the column names of `RawNumbers` and `Sorted`). Put this in Sorted Column:

```
=LARGE([RawNumbers],ROW()-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[Sorted]]))
```

[image]

I presume using a pivot table is not a viable option... but these are how you could accomplish your objective of sorting by formula.